# Не получается передать данные из дочерней активности в родительскую

Tags: java, android, android-intent, key

Есть 2 активности, родительская:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private Button mButton;
        private TextView mTextView;
        private String mResalt;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_text);

            mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bottom);
            mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = Test_Activity.newIntent(MainActivity.this);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            mResalt = Test_Activity.putText(data);

            mTextView.setText(mResalt);
        }
    }
```

И дочерняя:

```
public class Test_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mEditText;
    private TextView mTextView;

    private static final String keyString = "com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.answer_shown";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_test);
        String text = String.valueOf(mTextView); // нужно передать этот текст в родительскую активность
        TextResult(text);
    }

    public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext){
        Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, Test_Activity.class);
        return intent;
    }

    public static String putText (Intent resalt){
        return resalt.getStringExtra(keyString);
    }

    private void TextResult (String text){
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra(text, keyString);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    }
}
```

Я пытаюсь передать текст из дочерней активности в родительскую, но текст в родительской активности лишь заменяется на пустое место, а не на тот текст, который должен быть получен из дочерней активности.
При отладке обнаружил это:
[image]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что с этим делать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Параметры перепутаны `data.putExtra(text, keyString);` а нужно `data.putExtra(keyString, text);`
2. `String.valueOf(mTextView)` - Не думаю, что это будет полезно. Если нужно взять строку из TextView, нужно делать `mTextView.getText().toString()`
3. Код должен делать то, о чем говорит. Вот такое недопустимо (метод называется putText, а на деле делает getStringExtra):

   `public static String putText (Intent resalt){
       return resalt.getStringExtra(keyString);
   }`

Также метод TextResult() - вообще по имени не понятно что он должен делать.
`private void TextResult (String text)`

4. По стилю кода: Методы в Java никогда не начинаются с больших букв `private void TextResult (String text)` - так не принято. Имена классов не должны содержать нижнее подчеркивание `public class Test_Activity extends AppCompatActivity` - так не принято

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и отдельное спасибо за замечания по оформлению кода!